# Как убрать миллисекунды в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Как убрать миллисекунды при выводе даты?

```
<p>{{ $data_zakaza.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") }}</p>
```

Метод **ToString()** вызывает ошибку:

```
Call to undefined function ToString()
```

Comment: какая связь между миллисекундами и непределенной функцией?

Comment: Я просто нашел функцию ToString() и решил её применить

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php ```date('Y-m-d H:i', $time);```

Comment: очень интересный подход. А где ты ее нашел и к чему решил применить? И, главное, зачем?

Comment: Нашел отсюда: https://overcoder.net/q/903316/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-datetimeuctnowtimeofday
Предполагал, что этот метод сработает

Comment: А то что по ссылке находится ответ для `С#` вас не смутило?

Answer (score 1):

В Laravel вы можете использовать `Carbon` для дат. Для этого достаточно определить в вашей модели свойство

```
protected $dates = ['data_zakaza'];
```

Если модель не используется, то перед передачей в шаблон можно сделать так:

```
$data_zakaza = Carbon::parse($data_zakaza);
```

Теперь при выводе в шаблоне можно использовать форматирование:

```
<p>{{ $data_zakaza.format("y-m-d H:i:s") }}</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант можно просто обрезать строку:

```
$data_zakaza = mb_substr($zakaz->data_zakaza, 0, 19);
```

Comment: Плохой вариант. Даты нужно хранить и обрабатывать как даты. Что если формат data_zakaza изменится? С типом "дата" такого произойти не может.